# How to fill a gridview from XSD file tableadapter query based on a selected paramter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying fill out a GridView from a created table adapter connection. I can easily do this with an SQL data source but, I need to do the same with the table adapter. Here is the ASP Gridview code. Which resides on a testpage.aspx page I'm using.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Here is the C# code I am using to define the parameter that will be placed, enable the table adapter query, the datatable code to view it and a FillBy method.

```
int diff = 1;
var testVar = new RenewalReportConnectionTableAdapters.vPolicyRenewal_CurrentMonthTableAdapter();//this enables to query 
var testVarTbl = new RenewalReportConnection.vPolicyRenewal_CurrentMonthDataTable(); // this enables me to view the query

testVar.FillByDiff(testVarTbl, diff);

GridView2.DataSource = testVarTbl;
```

the parameter is used a the SQL statement that defines what data I am returning. Here it is you need to see it.

```
where (Year(ExpDate) = YEAR(getdate()))  AND DATENAME(month, ExpDate) = 
DATENAME(MONTH, (Dateadd(Month, @Diff,GETDATE())))
```

If it's 0 (@Diff), it brings me back the current month, if it's one, it brings me back next month. I can create three seperate SQL data sources for these three options, but I want the user to have the ability to hit a button and choose.

My issue is: it runs with no errors but, the GridView is not there. There is no data filled and not view to see. With or without the parameter.

Any guidance on how to fill and display would be greatly appreciated.